# What does this expression mean in thymeleaf form validation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In a tutorial I see, after validating a form, we want to display the error text on the html page using thymeleaf. The code written to show the errors of several fields in a form in order is as follows:

```
<ul>
     <li class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('contact.*')}" th:text="${error}"></li>
                </ul>
```

Also, the object to which we attach the form information is called contact.

Now I have some questions:

what is #? What is fields.errors? And why is .* used at the end of contact? If this is a regex, it should show errors if we remove .* from the end. But if we do not use .*, the errors will not be displayed. Why?

Comment: Does this help: [Baeldung spring-thymeleaf-error-messages](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-error-messages)

Comment: @DirkDeyne I looked at this, unfortunately, no, it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*what is `#`? What is `fields.errors`?*"

Don't separate those two pieces. The question should be "*What is `#fields.errors`?*"

Thymeleaf has a variety of so-called [expression utility objects](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#appendix-b-expression-utility-objects) which are values which begin with a `#`.

They are basically classes in the Thymeleaf library which provide generally useful functions you may want to use in your templates.

As you can see from the documentation [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#expression-utility-objects):

> Thymeleaf will offer us a set of utility objects that will help us perform common tasks in our expressions.

But for `#fields.errors`, the object `#fields` is not a part of the core Thymeleaf library. It is part of the Spring dialect of Thymeleaf.

Spring's version (dialect) of Thymeleaf adds a number of enhancements over standard Thymeleaf. This enhancement is aimed at making it easier for you to handle form validation errors in your templates.

You can see the JavaDoc for `Fields` [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring4/3.0.2.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/spring4/expression/Fields.html):

> Expression Object for performing form-field-related operations inside Thymeleaf Standard Expressions in Spring environments.

You can also see from the JavaDoc that this `Fields` class has various useful methods for accessing any field validation errors provided by your Spring validation services.

One of these is:

> `public List<String> errors(String field)`

---

"*why is `.*` used at the end of `contact`?*"

For the example of `${#fields.errors('contact.*')}`, that is a Thymeleaf expression which uses this `#fields.errors` method to access all the error messages associated with all the fields in the `contact` object.

Here the `*` symbol is a wildcard for "all fields".

Don't read it as `.*` - a regular expression meaning "any character, zero one or many times".

Read it as a dot operator (`.`) separating the object name `contact` from the field name (in this case `*` for all fields).

You could replace `*` with a single field name from `contact` to get only the errors for that one field, instead of all (`*`) fields.

---

In the example in your question, the Thymeleaf expression is therefore accessing a list of error messages - the `List<String>` return value from the `errors` method it uses. It can therefore iterate over the messages in that list (if there are any).

And that is what the code does using `th:each="error ...` - using standard Thymleaf iteration logic.